# How to push similar index type key in single object in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, object

Following is the type of object I am getting from a result -

```
{ 
  length1: [ '45' ],
  length2: [ '42' ],
  length3: [ '21' ],
  weight1: [ '12' ],
  weight2: [ '34' ],
  weight3: [ '45' ] 
}
```

Now I want to group them on the index basis, i.e -

```
{length1: 45, weight1: 12}
{length1: 45, weight2: 12}
{length1: 45, weight3: 12}
..........................
..........................
..........................
{lengthn: 45, weightn: 12}
```

Now this may go upto **n**

Following is my try with which I am able to break them, but unable to combine into similar objects, Let me know how can I achieve the following result.

```
var result = {}; 
result.bol = { 
  length1: [ '45' ],
  length2: [ '42' ],
  length3: [ '21' ],
  weight1: [ '12' ],
  weight2: [ '34' ],
  weight3: [ '45' ] 
};
wresl = result.bol;

            for(tip in wresl) {
                var regex1 = /length/;
                var regex2 = /width/;
                var regex3 = /height/;
                var regex4 = /weight/;
                if(regex1.test(tip)) {
                    console.log(tip);
                    console.log(result.bol[tip]);
                } else if(regex2.test(tip)) {
                    console.log(tip);
                    console.log(result.bol[tip]);
                } else if(regex3.test(tip)) {
                    console.log(tip);
                    console.log(result.bol[tip]);
                } else if(regex4.test(tip)) {
                    console.log(tip);
                    console.log(result.bol[tip]);
                }
            }
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/02t92x36/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```js
var result = {}; 
result.bol = { 
  length1: [ '45' ],
  length2: [ '42' ],
  length3: [ '21' ],
  weight1: [ '12' ],
  weight2: [ '34' ],
  weight3: [ '45' ] 
};

out = [];

Object.keys(result.bol).forEach(function(key) {
  var m = key.match(/(\D+)(\d+)/),
      name = m[1],
      n = m[2] - 1;
  
  if(!out[n])
    out[n] = {};
  out[n][name] = Number(result.bol[key][0]);
});

document.write("<pre>"+JSON.stringify(out,0,3));
```

On a general note, instead of fixing a broken data structure like this, it's cleaner to consider a better one from the beginning.

Comment: Dry solution! Don't forget to append the index (`n`) to the property name.

Comment: @georg Its actually a result from user inserted xml which I parsed via xml2js

Comment: so their is a case as well when user may not fill weight1 but height1 only

Comment: @Trialcoder: in this case, there will be an object like `{height:25}`.

Answer (score 1):

With some javascript help, here is a solution:

```js
var result = {};
result.bol = {
  length1: ['45'],
  length2: ['42'],
  length3: ['21'],
  weight1: ['12'],
  weight2: ['34'],
  weight3: ['45']
};
var wresl = result.bol;

var out=[];
var re = /length(\d+)/;
for (prop in wresl) {
  var matches=prop.match(re);
  if (matches!=null) {
    var tmp={};
    var weight = 'weight' + matches[1];
    tmp[prop] = Number(wresl[prop][0]);
    tmp[weight] = Number(wresl[weight][0]);
    out.push(tmp);
  }
}

document.write('<pre>'+JSON.stringify(out,2,1));
```